# What is wrong wit this FINDSTR command on microsoft windows 10 enterprise machine

Tags: windows, command-prompt, findstr

trying to get this work for the past hour, but couldn't see what is wrong.

```
FINDSTR /M /C:"260255" productattributes_20190413_000001.775.txt>Err.txt
```

`string 260255` is available in the file `productattributes_20190413_000001.775.txt` and I am executing this command from the directory where this file is present. Err.txt is empty after executing this command.

full command -

```
C:\Users\nmangal\Desktop\feed_for_prod\price\attributes>FINDSTR /M /C:"260255" productattributes_20190413_000001.775.txt>Err.txt
```

Comment: Maybe the text file is UTF-16? Try `type yourfilename.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, Yes it was UTF-16 LE. Now it works. Please post this as an answer and I will accept. is there a way to change the encoding of all the files in a folder?

Comment: or is there a way to ignore encoding in the findstr command itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your file is in UTF-16, in which case `findstr` will not find the text, because of the intervening nulls.

Hence, one solution would be to convert the file to UTF-8.

I am not aware of any way to make `findstr` handle UTF-16. In fact, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Findstr) says,

> However, while the find command supports UTF-16, findstr does not.

So a different solution might be to use `find` instead.